# Extracting page dimensions from a PDF with a C++ program

Tags: c++, parsing, pdf, podofo

How can I extract the page dimensions from a PDF file with a C++ program ?

Is there any lightweight, cross-platform, easy to build/install, library that could help ?

Thanks :)

[EDIT]

I tried to build podofo under windows, but it didn't work.
LibHaru and PDFHummus are for rendering pdfs, not parsing their data.

**[EDIT & SOLUTION]**

I've finally built podofo under windows!

(btw, under Ubuntu, it was just a matter of `sudo apt-get install libpodofo0.9.0 libpodofo-dev libpodofo-utils` )

It was actually a CMake 2.8.10 bug, switching back to 2.8.3 solved the problem ( [thanks](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/438435/windres.exe-invalid-option-w-) )

If anyone is interested, here's how to get started with podofo under windows (I'll demonstrate how to build the debug/shared version):

1. download the required libraries (freetype, jpeg, openssl, tiff, zlib) and install them (I suggest, copying all the files under `LIB_NAME\lib` in `C:\libraries\lib` , same thing for `\include` )
2. install [CMake 2.8.3](http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/)
3. add MinGW\bin and CMake\bin to the `PATH`
4. download [podofo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/download.html#podofo) and uzip it somewhere, let's say in `C:\downloads\podofo-0.9.2`
5. create a new directory `C:\downloads\podofo-0.9.2\podofo-shared-debug`
6. open the command prompt then type `cd C:\downloads\podofo-0.9.2\podofo-shared-debug`
7. run this command to prepare a MinGW makefile for the debug/shared version of podofo

   ```
   cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\libraries\include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\libraries\lib -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
   ```
8. then just call make

   ```
   mingw-make.exe
   ```
9. if you're using codeblocks, here's how to install/use podofo:

9.1. copy the following

```
podofo-0.9.2\podofo --> C:\libraries\podofo-0.9.2\include\podofo
podofo-0.9.2\src --> C:\libraries\podofo-0.9.2\include\src
podofo-0.9.2\podofo-shared-debug\podofo_config.h --> C:\libraries\podofo-0.9.2\include\podofo_config.h

podofo-0.9.2\podofo-shared-debug\src\libpodofo.dll.a --> C:\libraries\podofo-0.9.2\lib-shared-debug\libpodofo.dll.a

podofo-0.9.2\podofo-shared-debug\src\libpodofo.dll --> C:\libraries\podofo-0.9.2\bin-shared-debug\libpodofo.dll
```

9.2. use `-lpodofo` in the linker options then add `C:\libraries\podofo-0.9.2\include` to the compiler's search directories and `C:\libraries\podofo-0.9.2\lib-shared-debug` to the linker's search directories

Getting back to my initial question, the  closest answer to "how to extract the page dimensions from a PDF file with a C++ program (using podofo) ?" is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <podofo/podofo.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument document;
    try
    {
        document.Load("path/to/the/file.pdf");
    }
    catch (PdfError& e )
    {
        // a password is required to read this pdf
        return -1;
    }


    try
    {
        PoDoFo::PdfRect pageSize = document.GetPage(0)->GetPageSize();  // yes, it's "0-based"
        std::cout << "width: " << pageSize.GetWidth() << "\t\theight: " << pageSize.GetHeight() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (PdfError& e )
    {
        // page number error
        return -2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried PoDoFo. I spent the last few hours trying to build it under windows, and it simply won't :(

I downloaded all the necessary libs (freetype, jpeg, openssl, tiff, zlib). I used cmake-gui to generate the build files for codeblocks. When I tried to build podofo_static there were some build errors... :/

Comment: Did you build all the libs yourself? If you post a question about that I might be able to help.

Comment: I downloaded the dev files (I have the /include and /lib of each library)